# Why I can not see database in AWS RDS MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am working on a project where I am supposed to run a python script (using AWS Lambda) once in 24 hours and whatever data is collected during the run that will be stored in AWS RDS MySQL database.

I have created a database identifier in RDS. Later, using jupyter notebook, I created the database in the same database identifier.

My problem is that I am able to read, write to/from the database and perform all possible operations on the database. However, when I open AWS RDS, anywhere I am unable to see the database that I've created!

[image: in DB Name, it is blank, though the database exists!]

I did some google, and found that it is maybe due to the region is set to a different area. I checked for those possibilities too. Still, I have no idea why it is happening?

Also, when I click on "Query Editor" in AWS RDS, it prompts me to create the database. But the database is already there and also contains the data!!! It is just that I can not see that!

[image]

What possibly could be wrong here?

Comment: Right in your screenshot: "Currently, query editor only supports Aurora Serverless databases." Yours isn't one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in their [press release](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/05/amazon-rds-data-api-and-query-editor-available-additional-regions/), RDS Query editor for Aurora is currently available only on Serverless databases.

You could try converting your DB to Serverless ([this answer provides very useful tips to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51568132/how-do-you-switch-between-standard-and-serverless-configurations-in-amazon-auror)). But as your project seems to be brand new, you're probably better off creating a brand new Aurora Serverless DB, as described in [those AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.create.html).
Good luck!

Comment: I created another MySQL database with AWS Aurora. Now I am able to use the query editor. But Still, I am unable to view my database. I mean that if I use MySQL workbench then I can click on the name of the database and view the database. So, how it can be done in AWS RDS? This is because the company I am working for is not a tech company. So, they are just concerned with the data. Whenever I want to view data, I can write SQL queries and see it but I can't ask my employer to learn SQL! Any possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge and understanding you cannot view your databases by simply accessing your AWS RDS dashboard. If you are using `MySQL` as your database then better install `MySQL Workbench` and access your desired database via it.